# Word for not yet cashed loss or gain of money from a investment

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say I put 100 dollars in Bitcoin. And the value doubles (or halves).

I did not gain more bitcoin, so saying I **earned** 100 dollars is wrong.
If I cash out now, I will earn 100 dollars. This is correct, but quite a mouthful

Preferring some word that fits in the following sentence :
I invested in crypto and I have ____ 100 dollars.

Comment: The problem is that the amount one earns/loses fluctuates with the market. What can be 50 bucks right now could potentially be zero tomorrow. or even later in the day. So, one word will not work unless you mean at a very specific point in time.

Comment: @Lambie correct, that is why I'm looking for a word mening "if i cash out now"

Comment: Well, there is to cash out or to net out. There is also make: I invested in X and **made** Y dollars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *I invested in crypto and I (currently) have an **unrealized** profit of $50.*

**unrealized** (adj.)

> Not turned into cash by sale
>
> *the stock's unrealized gains*
>
> *That brings his personal unrealized gains to over $840 million.* —
> Chris Morris, Fortune, 29 Nov. 2021 [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unrealized)

> Not converted into money.
>
> *unrealized property assets*
>
> *But if we are right on the analysis and willing to sit tight, we will eventually recover unrealized losses and make money.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unrealized)

---

> What is an **unrealized gain/loss**?
>
> You’re probably already familiar with the concept of gains and losses.
> But here’s a quick review: A gain is when your investment – let’s say
> a stock – increases in value after you purchase it. A loss is when the
> stock decreases in value after your purchase.
>
> Until you actually sell the investment, your gains or losses are
> simply numbers on a piece of paper.
>
> **Unrealized gains/losses** aren’t “locked in.” This means that if you’re
> holding onto assets with **unrealized losses**, it’s possible for them to
> become **unrealized gains** when the market is having a good week. Or vice
> versa.
>
> ["Realized vs. **Unrealized** Gains  and Losses: What’s the Difference?";
> marcus.com](https://www.marcus.com/us/en/resources/personal-finance/realized-vs-unrealized-gains-losses)

> An **unrealized**, or **"paper" gain or loss** is a theoretical profit
> or deficit that exists on balance, resulting from an investment that
> has not yet been sold for cash. [Chris Gallant; *'How are realized
> profits different from **unrealized** or so-called **"paper"
> profits**?'*](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/realizedprofitsvsunrealizedprofits.asp)
> (Added to capture the suggestion made by Yosef Baskin in a comment)

Comment: You could say a *profit of 50 unrealized dollars*.

Comment: Also a *paper* profit or loss.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Put that in an answer and turn your paper rep gain into realized points you can put in Gringotts Wizarding Bank.

Comment: This is one of those times that there is one precise and perfect answer.

Comment: Yes, but 50 unrealized dollars is odd. unrealized is really just an accounting term and not used like this. Sorry. People do not talk like this. unrealized is completely wrong here. Especially since bitcoin markets fluctuate wildly and an unrealized loss/gain would only be reflected in your personal accounting entries., for taxes, for example.

Comment: I've reworded the OP's example to read more idiomatically.

Comment: "You could say *a profit of 50 unrealized dollars*." <— NOT.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I was using syntax in the examples provided by the OP. *I agree* it's stilted and I reworded the example.

Comment: @Lambie - That's what is used in places like TIAA.  They do have some weird terminology in finance.

Comment: @aparente001 Of course, it is an accounting term used in finance and taxation. It is not used by people speaking in everyday language. So, I keep seeing the upvotes rise and it is really getting on my nerves. :)

Comment: It may be that the general public does use the term unrealized gains because it was in the news in the U.S. quite a bit at the end of 2021, with a congressional proposal to tax unrealized gains. (How they would account for unrealized losses, I have no idea.) https://www.google.com/amp/s/money.yahoo.com/amphtml/democrats-unveil-billionaires-tax-on-unrealized-capital-gains-131232669.html

Comment: @lambie - I had to learn it to deal with TIAA.  Not fun.